# Rotation-invariant homogeneous distribution

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Can you tell me for every $\alpha  \in \mathbb{R}$, whether there is a non-zero homogeneous and rotation-invariant distribution on $\mathbb{R}^n$ with degree of homogeneity $\alpha$?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. When $\alpha>-n$, the obvious candidate $|x|^\alpha$ works. Also, if $f$ is a distribution that is homogeneous of degree $\alpha$, then $\Delta f$ is a homogeneous distribution of degree $\alpha-2$ (and rotational invariance is preserved). This allows you to cover the range $\alpha\le -n$ as well.

There is one exception: we do not get a nonzero distribution with $\alpha=-2$ by taking the Laplacian of $|x|^0\equiv 1$. Take $\Delta \log |x|$ instead.